# New MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, setup-project

I just need some guidance. I'm fairly new to MVC3 and to web development in general. I want to create my own project that will involve data storage/access (SQL server db) and user log in functionality. I'm not sure were to start, there seem to be so many ways for this and following tutorials doesn't really give the experience of setting up real life project (or its just my impression). Would you guys suggest starting from an empty MVC3 project, or perhaps use the scaffolding feature and build on top of it and use the membership provider built into it ? Some tutorials (by Scott Hanselman) actually explain how to copy and paste the membership feature into a new project. Is this approach suggested ? Any suggestions will help! Thanks!

Comment: While in general, tutorials don't usually seem to correlate to real life situations, I had good luck with the ASP.NET MVC Music Store tutorial.  You might try starting there.  The whole tutorial only took me a few hours.

Comment: The [NerdDinner](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/introducing-the-nerddinner-tutorial) tutorial is very good. It has log in component to it. The [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site has plenty of useful tutorials that you can use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some tutorials

[MVC 3 with razor](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript)

[ASP.Net website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)

[MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)

[Strongly typed helpers in mvc](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx)

[Brad Wilson's Blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/aspnet_mvc/)

[MVC Subdomain routing](http://hanssens.org/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx)

[MVC Partial Views](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels)

Some javascript for MVC

[MVC Javascript frameworks](http://goutamdey.com/2010/01/02/5-javascript-mvc-frameworks-2/)

[JSON and MVC](http://storypodders.com/blog/blog/using-a-jsonresult-action-in-asp-net-mvc-to-get-data-via-ajax-and-jquery/)

[Form update using JSON in MVC](http://www.marcdormey.com/index.php/archives/update-form-fields-with-json-result-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

I'm just starting too, I found [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc) very helpful, especially the videos on the left.

But what I found *extremely* helpful is the [MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/64379) and the [Contoso University](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) site (I recommend to download as PDF; you can see a button to do so at the top).

Answer (score 0):

The [NerdDinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) tutorial is a great way to start with *ASP.NET MVC*, although the online version is slightly out of date. However, I can strongly recommend the book that this tutorial (in its updated version) is the first chapter of: [Professional ASP.NET MVC 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118076583).